# $R=0$ solution in field equations

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, modified-gravity

I am dealing with some General Relativity extensions and I am not sure about my knowledge in basic GR since I am having some weird troubles with what I think are basic concepts.

As far as I know, if we have a field equation (we can think about this as, for example, EFE) in vacuum, $R_{\mu\nu}-\dfrac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R=0$. In a more general sense, think about it as some equation which contains in the left hand side objects like $R$ or $R_{\mu\nu}$ and its derivatives, but not higher tensors as Riemann) we can see that the trace of the Einstein equation implies $R=0$, and plugging this into the original equation gives us $R_{\mu\nu}=0$. Now, is it correct to say that every solution of $R_{\mu\nu}-\dfrac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R=0$ must have neccesairly $R_{\mu\nu}=0$? I think this is true.

Since the Schwarzschild metric has $R=0$, can we conclude that a field equation in the general form I described before verifies Schwarzschild as a solution if Einstein equation $R_{\mu\nu}-\dfrac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R=0$  is verified?

I mean, suppose $D(X,Y)$ denotes some function that can contain derivatives of its arguments, and then we have the field equation $D(R,R_{\mu\nu})+R_{\mu\nu}-\dfrac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R=0$. If Einstein is verified, $R_{\mu\nu}-\dfrac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R=0$ and then $D(R,R_{\mu\nu})=0$, but since $D(R,R_{\mu\nu})$ can only have derivatives of $R$ and $R_{\mu\nu}$, and Einstein is verified so $R=0$ and $R_{\mu\nu}=0$, of course its derivatives will be zero and $D(R,R_{\mu\nu})=0$, so $R=0$ is a solution and since Schwarzschild has $R=0$ it must be a solution to this extended theory. Is my reasoning correct? Thanks

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the extendeed theory you're studying? Also your question is kinda not clear.

Answer (score 1):

$$R_{\mu\nu} - \cfrac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R=0\Rightarrow R=0\rightarrow R_{\mu\nu}=0$$

The above statement holds for the absence of matter when one's dealing with Einstein Gravity.

Let's consider $R^2$ gravity:

$$RR_{\mu\nu} -\cfrac{1}{4}R^2g_{\mu\nu} + (g_{\mu\nu}\Box - \nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu})R^2=0 $$

$R=0$ is a solution. This does not imply that $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ somehow.

$R=C\rightarrow R_{\mu\nu} =g_{\mu\nu}\cfrac{C}{4}$ is also a solution.

Both these solutions satisfy the trace equation:
$$\Box R=0$$

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello! Yes, that's what I am looking at. Suppose we have some field equation derived from the action $S=\dfrac{1}{16\pi G}\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} (R+\alpha R^2)$, which would be Einstein + the field equation you wrote. In the case Einstein holds, $R=0$ and $R_{\mu\nu}=0$, so the total field equation would be automatically satisfied, right? I mean, Schwarzschild ($R=0$) would be the trivial solution to this field equation?

Comment: Yes, in Starobinsky gravity Schwarzchild is a solution,

Comment: If we generalize to higher derivative theories like $f(R)$ or Gauss-Bonnet, this still holds? If Schwarschild is a solution of all this teories, I dont understand why people claims higher derivatives theories of gravity are singularity-free for black holes or Big Bang.

Comment: In f(R) surely it does not hold if the f(R) function is not specified. Gauss Bonnet it does not hold either, the derivatives of Riemann and Ricci are still present.

Comment: I don't understand, if we impose Einstein holds, then Ricci tensor and scalar vanish and then fourth derivative theory without Kretschmann scalar should work. Do you know then how can some $f(R)$ theories be singularity-free?

Comment: I dont know the part about singularities. The problem with your thinking is that you're not dealing with Einstein. You modify Einstein. What happens in Einstein Gravity may not hold for a modified theory.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Yeah,, I wanted to see what happens in singularity-free gravities that generalize Einstein. Since Einstein has singularities and singularity-free gravities obviously not, as the coupling constant of modifications go to 0 one should be able to see a singularity emergence.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, maybe Schwarzchild is a solution of all those theories, but we cannot see it immediately, since $R_{\mu\nu} =0$ or $R=0$ cannot be obtained from the field equations if we trace them. Maybe the solution to the field equations if we adjust the constants of integration will end being Schwarzchild but we cannot see it immedaitely.

Comment: Or even maybe Schwarzchild cannot be obtained by integration if the equations are too hard to be solved exactly but the Schwarzchild metric will satisfty  the equations.

Comment: @NambuGotto The point is that although Schwarzschild is one solution of certain higher derivative theories, it is not the only solution. So Schwarzschild is no longer the unique spherically symmetric solution, unlike in GR (Birkhoff's theorem).

Comment: @Avantgarde Yes! Thank you so much. The thing now is, how are this new black holes? Or even, is the Schwarzschild-like solution the same as GR? Or, for example, singularity gets soften? We know for example that Kretschmann scalar in GR for Schwarzschild goes like $1/r^6$, the higher derivative terms should weaken this singularity in principle. Is there any easy way to check all this?

Comment: The Kretschmann scalar is constructed from derivatives of the metric, hence does not "feel" that you're working on some higher derivative theory of gravitation.

Comment: @ApolloRa That's true, if the Schwarzschild metric is the same as in GR then the Kretschmann scalar will be the same as in GR. In the other black hole metric solutions this can be different.

Comment: What do you mean by "if the Schwarzschild metric is the same as in GR "? The Schwarzchild metric is a metric of the form: $f(r) = 1 + O(1/r)$. All metrics with this behavior have the same properties.

Comment: @ApolloRa Yes, if we have a Schwarzschild metric with the form you said we will obtain the same Kretschmann scalar behaviour $1/r^6$. Other thing is we have a metric similar to Schwarzschild but with terms like $1/r e^{-mr}$ or something similar, which is a solution of $f(R)=R+aR^2$ gravity in linear order. I am right now calculating the Kretschmann scalar for this metric and i think the behaviour will be slower than  $1/r^6$, altought I am having some trouble with xAct.

Comment: A metric with $O(e^{-mr}/r)$ term is no longer a Schwrzchild metric. If i understand correctly this solution is obtained from perturbation around shcwarzchlid spacetime. We maybe can say that this is a Schwarzchild black hole with corrections due to the higher order curvature terms. But this isn't a pure Schwarzchild metric. Just write Kretschmann[CD][] and the calculation is immediate.

Comment: @ApolloRa Of course, this new metric isn't Schwarzchild, it is like a generalized Schwarzchild. Exactly! If we take the typical spherical symmetric and static metric with unknown functions $B(r)$ and $A(r)$ in the $00$ component and $11$ component respectively, and we linearise the metric as $B(r)=1+V(r)$ (the same for $A(r)$ with a perturbation $W(r)$), the solution to the $R+aR^2$ gravity (or higher terms gravity, as Gauss-Bonnet) field equations with the metric above turns out to have terms with exponential over $r$ as you correctly said. I've tried that ofc, but I am having some bugs :(.

Comment: There's this xAct group maybe you can ask there: https://groups.google.com/g/xact

Comment: @NambuGotto The exact Schwarzschild solution is the same in different theories, whichever it is a solution of. But aspects of black hole stability, for instance, are different in different theories. For stability, we have to study the evolution of tiny perturbations away from exact Schwarzschild. This is done by linearizing the equations of motion and finding the equations that govern the evolution of perturbations. For example, look at this old paper on stability of Schwarzschild in 4th order gravity - https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.32.379